# Invoking PUT and DELETE in Express Without Using AJAX

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having a problem invoking `PUT` and `DELETE` requests in Express.

I am using `MongoDB` and `Mongoose` and am trying to create a basic blog with posts and comments. From what I understand, forms do not pass in any methods other than `POST` and `GET` and that in order to use `PUT` or `DELETE` I can create a hidden input type with the value "PUT" in my form. What I don't understand is how I would use this value in the back end to invoke the `PUT` function?

**Route**

```
app.get('/message/:id', function(request, response) {
Post.findOne({_id: request.params.id})
    .populate('comments')
    .exec(function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("There was an error getting the comments.");
        } else {
            console.log(post);
            response.render('post', { post: post });
        }
    });
});

app.put('/message/:id', function(request, response) {
Post.findOne({id: request.params.id}, function(err, post) {
    var comment = new Comment({ name: request.body.name, text: request.body.text });
    comment._post = post._id;
    post.comments.push(comment);
    comment.save(function(err) {
        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error');
            } else {
                response.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

**Markup**

```
        <form action="/message/<%= data[i]._id %>" method="post">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="message"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="PUT">
            <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
        </form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can use a query string parameter like ?method=put on the action of a post form  and use req.params or req.query to read it. That way you keep the method data separate from your form data then call the appropriate code if req.query.method === 'put' so your post route handler handles post and put

Comment: Hey Glenn, thanks so much for the reply. I am unfortunately new to programming and thus, am kind of confused on the solution that you've suggested. I think I'm in a little over my head as I'm not even sure about the req.query.method==='put' that you've written. Thanks for the help but I think I better go over some more tutorials.

Comment: See my answer. Also is there a reason why you can't use JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

this is not a full solution, it is only meant to expand on your questions about my comment recommendation.

```
// post route
app.post('/message', function(request, response) {
    // post code
});

// put and delete
app.post('/message/:id', function(request, response) {
    if (request.query.method === 'PUT') {
        //put code
    }
    else if (request.query.method === 'DELETE') {
        // delete code
    }
});
```

HTML for a put (query string method=PUT)

```
<form action="/message/<%= data[i]._id %>?method=PUT" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="PUT Comment">
</form>
```

HTML for a delete (query string method=DELETE)

```
<form action="/message/<%= data[i]._id %>?method=DELETE" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="DELETE Comment">
</form>
```

HTML for a post (no id or query string)

```
<form action="/message" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
</form>
```

Comment: Hey vbranden, thank you so much for your help! All I had to do was use method-override along with what you wrote and now everything works great. I didn't know that "method" in the "action" part of the HTML form was actually an object that could hold data that you could extract using request.query.method. Extremely cool and very important to know. Thanks again!

Comment: To clarify, the query string is parsed into key value pairs by express. So the value does not need to be method, it could  be ?icecream=POST  and then you would look for the method in request.query.icecream . You should read up on query strings if you get a chance